# Justice through soul-reincarnation

Tags: science, reincarnation, justice

A pure, almost metaphysical but from the inside of me:
How would it sound that there is an afterlife of the more that 00 billion people that ever lived on earth since the begging of our species (as calculated).
And more specifically those who have lost their lives in vein or with an unjust way, through war or crime or even physical disaster.

How much JUSTICE could be embodied in our Universe and could these lost lives have a second chance as energy (a soul) in another parallel universe, or in other case, just be re-incarnated in our Earth?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several lessons in Buddhist doctrine -- and that two of them are:

- Things happen for reasons, and what happens isn't necessarily "unjust"
- Things happen (or stop happening) whether you like it or not, sometimes for reason which are outside your control -- you might try to anticipate that (e.g. knowing that things are impermanent), and to develop an appropriate attitude and reaction to events like that when they do occur.

You might listen to, for example, [Ask A Monk: Karma in a Holocaust](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBmvLLffvg0).